# permission over write after channel creation, using discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm having some issues with giving the `message.author` and staff permission to see the channel right after it's created, the issue is, when the channel's parent (category) is changed, it syncs the permissions of the parent (category), which disallows the user and staff to see the channel, I'm not sure how to fix this, I wish I explained well, if you have any questions, please ask.

Here is my code:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'new',
  category: 'Ticket',
  description: 'Creates a new ticket.',
  aliases: ['newticket'],
  usage: 'New',
  userperms: [],
  botperms: [],
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(!message.channel.id == process.env.COMMAND_T) return;
if(!client.userTickets) {
  client.userTickets = new Map();

  const channels = message.guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => {
    if(channel) return channel.name.startsWith('t-');
    });

    if(channels) {
      for (i in Array.from(channels)) {
        client.userTickets.set(i, +i + 1);
    }
  }
}
console.log(client.userTickets)
        if(client.userTickets.has(message.author.id)) {
            return message.channel.send('<@' + message.author.id + 'You already have a ticket, please close it then run this command again!').then(m => m.delete({timeout: 10000}));
        }
        message.guild.channels.create(`t-${client.userTickets.size + 1}`, {
            permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                    id: message.author.id,
                    allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                },
                {
                    id: process.env.ROLE_STAFF,
                    allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                },
                {
                    id: process.env.ROLE_MEMBER,
                    deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
                }
            ],
            type: 'text',
        }).then(async channel => {
            channel.setParent(process.env.TICKET_C);
            client.userTickets.set(message.author.id, client.userTickets.size + 1);
            message.channel.send(`<@` + message.author.id + `>, Done, go to your ticket! ${channel}`).then(m => m.delete({timeout: 10000}));
            client.users.cache.get(message.author.id).send(`Your ticket has been opened, go take a look: ${channel}`)
            channel.send(`Hi <@` + message.author.id + `>, Hello and welcome to your DwaCraft ticket!`);
            channel.send(`https://tenor.com/view/is-there-something-i-can-help-you-with-dan-levy-david-david-rose-schitts-creek-gif-20776045`);
            
            const logchannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === process.env.TICKET_L);
            
            if(logchannel) {
                logchannel.send(`There was a new ticket created by <@${message.author.id}>! Channel: <#${channel.id}>`);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note: I've researched but I didn't find any answer.

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
message.guild.channels.create(`t-${client.userTickets.size + 1}`, {
                type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
                permissionOverwrites: [
                    {
                        id: process.env.ROLE_STAFF,
                        allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                    },
                    {
                        id: message.author.id,
                        allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                    },
                ],
                parent: process.env.CATEGORY
            });
```

This code is mine, but it is shortened, if you like the complete one send me DM

P.S I just have it for my ticket system

Comment: I forgot to edit the question, I found a way around the problem, by setting a parent first **then** change the permissions, I have a new problem now, I'm new to databases, but I want to make the tickets databases. (I'll open another question for that though.)

Comment: Well, I hope I can help you, you can find me how: ! Richi OV#1700 or in my community https://discord.com/invite/xEUDMGTeRt